# error messages with main_activity java file

Tags: java, android-button

When attempting to build an app in android I am getting error messages with main_activity.java file concerning placements of ; or ) or } but I don't understand why. Can someone help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Button mButton;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_quiz);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //open url using Intent
          String url = "http://www.cancunsteve.com/capecod/mobilepopquiz2.htm";
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(intent);

        }
      )
    };
  }
```

Comment: don't see the point of your question. sorry. call it what you wish. the java file has errors. that's the issue here. believe javascript runs only on a browser? but the button in my code is intended to open a browser

Comment: Your new View.OnClickListener() is not closed. There's no '}' corresponding to opening brace. Your MainActivity is not closed as well.

Honestly, that's like asking strangers to spellcheck for you.

Comment: made changes. still getting errors trying to build. here's resulting file

Comment: can't send file get message it's too long for comment

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example, your onClickListener for the Button was incorrectly closed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private Button mButton;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_quiz);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //open url using Intent
          String url = "http://www.cancunsteve.com/capecod/mobilepopquiz2.htm";
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(intent);

        } //close OnClick
      }); //close onClickListener
    } //close onCreate
  } //close Main
```